# Tips for resurrecting agile cards with medics

Tags: the-witcher-3

First of all I don't know if I'm doing it wrong but I can't seem to choose which row [agile cards](http://witcher.wikia.com/wiki/Gwent_agile_cards) are placed when I resurrect them using a [medic card](http://witcher.wikia.com/wiki/Gwent_medic_cards). Assuming you can't choose which row a resurrected agile card is placed on what is the algorithm used to decide which row they end up on? Is it totally random or is it deterministic? It seems like agile cards tend to go to the same row as the medic if possible, but I'm not confident that is always the case. Furthermore medics like the [Dun Banner Medic](http://witcher.wikia.com/wiki/Dun_Banner_Medic_(gwent_card)) don't align to the agile rows.

Comment: Just to make sure: When you say "agile" cards, you mean cards that can either be deployed in the melee or ranged rows, as is the case with most Scoia'tael units, correct?

Comment: @Nolonar yes. I added a link to those cards and the medic cards.